# Using camera rotation to make quad always appear in front of the camera (c++/opengl)

Tags: c++, math, opengl

I'm trying to make a quad appear always in front of the camera, I'm trying to start by aligning it with the camera on the x-z plane and making sure it always faces the camera. I used this code...

```
float ry = cameraRY+PI_2;
float dis = 12;
float sz = 4;

float x = cameraX-dis*cosf(ry);
float y = cameraY;
float z = cameraZ-dis*sinf(ry)+cosf(ry)*sz;

float x2 = x + sinf(ry)*sz;
float y2 = y + sz;
float z2 = z - cosf(ry)*sz;

glVertex3f(x,y,z);
glVertex3f(x2,y,z2);
glVertex3f(x2,y2,z2);
glVertex3f(x,y2,z);
```

But it didn't quite look right, it seemed that the quad was rotating around a invisible point that was rotating correctly around the camera. I don't really know how to change it or how to go about doing this, any help appreciated!

Edit: Forgot to mention,
cameraX,cameraY,cameraZ are the camera's x,y,z positions

cameraRX and cameraRY are the camera's x and y rotations (Z rotation is always zero)

Comment: maybe you want to switch to 2d render mode instead, rotating a quad exactly on front of the camera seems a bit weird and can be done in 2d render mode as well, and much easier. you can combine 3d and 2d modes in opengl, so you can draw User Interface to the screen over your 3d scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [old tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/billboarding/) on Lighthouse3D.  It describes several "billboarding" techniques, which I believe are what you want.

Comment: Marking this the right answer as people who see this question will probably be looking for this (I actually already used some techniques from that tutorial), in my case however, I actually needed the 3d transformations on my object.

I finally solved my problem by doing these transformations before the world was translated or rotated, then resetting the matrix (popping it and whatnot).

Comment: If this wasn't what you're looking for, feel free to un-accept.  I don't want to keep you from getting the appropriate answer.  You may want to clarify your question though.  Are you looking to draw some GUI?  Do you need an ortho projection with depth testing turned off?

Answer (score 1):

Let P be your model view projection matrix, and c be the center of the quad you are trying to draw.  You want to find a pair of vectors u, v that determine the edges of your quad,

```
Q = [ c-u-v, c-u+v, c-u-v, c+u-v ]
```

Such that u is pointing directly down in clip coordinates, while v is pointing to the right:

```
P(u) = (0, s, 0, 0)
P(v) = (s, 0, 0, 0)
```

Where s is the desired scale of your quad.  Suppose that P is written in block diagonal form,

```
    [   M   | t ]
P = [-----------]
    [ 0 0 1 | 0 ]
```

Then let m0, m1 be the first two rows of M.  Now consider the equation we got for P(u), substituting and simplifying, we get:

```
              [ 0 ]
P(u) ~> M u = [ s ]
              [ 0 ]
```

Which leads to the following solution for u, v:

```
u = s * m1 / |m1|^2
v = s * m0 / |m0|^2
```